# Insert of randomly generated data into PostgreSQL extremely slow;

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-12

I need to insert a very large data set into a table for testing purposes. I have created a script for exactly that purpose that generates purely random data. It works, but it performs so slowly that I'll be here for a month of Sundays awaiting completion.

A few details:

- The sources table has 150-million records
- There are three statistics_per_source
- sleep time is 5
- It currently takes about 4-minutes for 1000 inserts
- PostgreSQL-12

**Question**: What steps can I take to make the script below operate much faster than it currently does or what alternative approach would I take to insert this magnitude of random data?

---

```
TRUNCATE TABLE public.statistic RESTART IDENTITY;



SELECT 'Creating View Statistics for Sources' as progress;
DO $$
DECLARE
    sleep       integer;
    sps         integer;
    start       integer     := 1;
    increment   integer;
    remaining   integer     := increment;
BEGIN
    SELECT sleep INTO sleep FROM Constants;
    SELECT statistics_per_source  INTO sps FROM Constants;
    SELECT commit_chunk_size INTO increment FROM Constants;
    INSERT INTO Progress(dt, operation, progress) VALUES (now(), 'statistics from source', 'BEGIN INSERT');

LOOP
    SELECT count(*) INTO remaining FROM source WHERE id > start LIMIT 1;
    EXIT WHEN remaining = 0;
    INSERT INTO Progress(dt, operation, progress) VALUES (now(), 'statistics from source', 'Beginning Source=' || start);

    INSERT INTO statistic(created, value, classtype, source_id, source_created, brand)
    SELECT
       date(src.created + trunc(random() * 20) * '1 day'::interval) created,
       (random() * 100000)::int,
       CASE WHEN (random() > 0.5) THEN 'Views' ELSE 'CTR' END,
        src.id,
        src.created,
        NULL
       FROM source src
    CROSS JOIN
        (SELECT generate_series(1, sps) as value ) s
    WHERE src.id between start + 1 and start + increment;

    INSERT INTO Progress(dt, operation, progress) VALUES (now(), 'statistics from source', 'Committing source=' || start);
    COMMIT;
    PERFORM pg_sleep(sleep);
    start := start + increment;
END LOOP ;
END $$;
```

The table looks like this; I've intentionally avoided creating indices for now for insert performance.

```
CREATE TABLE public.statistic
(
    id bigint NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807 CACHE 1 ),
    created date NOT NULL,
    value double precision NOT NULL,
    classtype text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    data_source integer,
    production integer,
    source_id bigint,
    source_created date,
    brand integer,
    CONSTRAINT statistics_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: doing a count(*) with a where condition might slow it down some, you could exit the loop when the insert `@@rowcount` was zero...

Comment: @JasonGoemaat; That was the trick, what a difference. If you want to add it as an answer I'll give yo credit. Otherwise, I'll delete this question .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a count(*) with a where condition might slow it down some, you could exit the loop when the insert @@rowcount was zero

Comment: Took a week-long job down to under an hour. I owe you a virtual beer.

Comment: Thanks, Cheers!  